# How to automatically add your SecurityFilterChain to each @WebMvcTest sliced test?

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

Previously I configured application's web security by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

According to [the getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) it's as easy as:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  // override what you need
}
```

Since Spring Boot 2.7.0 and [Spring Security 5.7.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/5.7.0-M2) the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. The [suggested solution](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) now it to define your own `SecurityFilterChain` `@Bean`.

The problem I faced with while migrating my project is that the `@Configuration` file declaring `SecurityFilterChain` does not get applied within the `@WebMvcTest` sliced test (like it happened for `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`). And as a workaround I have to manually import this `@Configuration` into each `@WebMvcTest` test class.

Is there a way to add some configuration to already existing sliced tests (`@WebMvcTest`) so it was loaded automatically?
I know that the context of sliced test is controlled by the corresponding `META-INF/spring.factories` piece of code (since Spring Boot 2.7 it has changed to `META-INF/spring/slice-.imports`). For the current Spring Boot 2.7.1, the slice configuration is located [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureWebMvc.imports). Can I somehow add my `@Configuration` containing `SecurityFilterChain` to existing `@WebMvcTest` slice?